# Symfony 1.4 Analytics/Webmaster Tools

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have just taken over a dated but working website.  What would be the best way for me to implement Google Analytics Tracking Code and Web Master tools meta tag?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to add it is in the view.yml for the app (e.g. apps/frontend/config/view.yml) under the javascripts section:

```
default:
  javascripts:
    - /js/ga.js
```

Put the Google snippet in it's own file (e.g. ga.js), and drop it under the web/js folder.  Clear the cache (symfony cc) and reload a page, and the new tracking code should be on every page.

This is a fast way to get it on every page.  If you need a more robust solution, check out the [sfGoogleAnalyticsPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfgoogleanalyticsplugin) - although you may have to modify it slightly for Google's newer tracking codes.